# How we pass data in recycler view when we click on any one item it will shown in another activity.(Kotlin)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I created a recycler view and when we click on one item, this item will show in another activity.
My code link is - https://github.com/anandrex5/RecyclerView_AlertDialog_SplashScreen
Please review the code and give me the suggestion.

when we click on any item, the item will show in another activity using kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

In your CountriesApdapter.kt add a lambda function

```
  private var onItemClickListener:((String) -> Unit)? = null
```

Which would take in ArrayList as a paramater that we would pass onto the next activity.

```
 fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: (String) -> Unit) {
        onItemClickListener = listener
    }
```

Add a function in the same Adapter class to set the lambda function.
as we will call this function from the activity class.

Next, in your onBindViewHolder function set the onClickListener and call

```
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CountryViewHolder, position: Int) {

        holder.textViewCountryname.text= countryNameList.get(position)
        holder.textViewDetails.text  = detailsList.get(position)
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(imageList.get(position))

        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener {

             onItemClickListener?.let { it(countryNameList.get(position)) }

        }
    }
```

And now in your MainActivity.kt after creating your adapter object define the setOnClickListener function and pass in the lambda.

```
 adapter = CountriesAdapter(countryNameList,detailsList,imageList,this@MainActivity)

adapter.setOnItemClickListener{ countryClicked ->

      val intent = Intent(this,NextActivity::class.java);
      i.putExtra("country", countryClicked);
      startActivity(i); 

    
}
```

```
This is how your CountryAdapter will be looking after making all the changes

class CountriesAdapter(
    var countryNameList: ArrayList<String>,
    var detailsList: ArrayList<String>,
    var imageList: ArrayList<Int>,
     var context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CountriesAdapter.CountryViewHolder>(){

    class CountryViewHolder(itemView : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
    {
        var textViewCountryname : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewContryName)
        var textViewDetails : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDetails)
        var imageView : CircleImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView)
        var cardView : CardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView)

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CountryViewHolder {
        val view : View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.card_design,parent,false)
        return CountryViewHolder(view)

    }
     private var onItemClickListener:((String) -> Unit)? = null

   

    fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: (String) -> Unit) {
        onItemClickListener = listener
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        //here we need to size of the array
        //return 3

        return countryNameList.size

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CountryViewHolder, position: Int) {

        holder.textViewCountryname.text= countryNameList.get(position)
        holder.textViewDetails.text  = detailsList.get(position)
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(imageList.get(position))

          holder.cardView.setOnClickListener {

             onItemClickListener?.let { it(countryNameList.get(position)) }

        }
    }


}
```